# ubuntu 16.04 Wifi: Failed to activate connection

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, wireless

I'm trying to Connect to Hidden Wifi Network on Ubuntu 16.04, but it throws the message below:

```
Failed to activate connection
(2) Connection 'wl' is not available on the device wlan0 at this time.
```

Wireless Driver:

```
Broadcom Corporation: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n Driver
```

Can anyone please help? Thanks in Advance!!!